# Not saving the first seed data from my seed.rb file in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, seed

I wonder why the first data which is the agency, wasn't saved even if the syntax is just really correct.

Please take a look at my seed file:

db/seeds.rb

```
Agency.delete_all
puts "Creating agency: agency@example.com..."
Agency.create(email: 'agency@example.com', password: 'password')
puts "Done!\n\n"


Admin.delete_all
puts "Creating admin: admin@example.com..."
Admin.new
Admin.create(email: 'admin@example.com', password: 'password')
puts "Done!\n\n"
```

When I entered into the console, and hitted `User.all`

only the last data was saved and that was **"admin"**

Comment: Where are you saving a `User` object on your seed?

Comment: try to use `create!` instead of `create`. It will raise an exception if the create fails, providing you helpfull details (record invalid, etc...)

Comment: Already tried with or without the bang "!". @m_x . I tried without `delete_all` & it worked... but i dont understand why it isnt working with the delete_all..

Comment: there may be some validations which are not allowed to create new `Agency` so use `create!` as suggested by m_x

Comment: actually, the first version of the seed file has `create!` but it also didn't work. Tried without delete_all and it worked. Please explain to me, what could be the reason...

Comment: is there any relation between `agency` and `admin` if yes there is chance of agency deletion when you are using `Admin.delete_all`

Comment: Thank you but i didnt put any relations. anyway thanks for all suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your suggestions...

I tried removing the `delete_all` and it worked.

Sorry for such novice questions.